# Android edittext with uneditable string at end

Tags: android, android-edittext

Hello everybody I'm doing an app which has an uneditable string at the end of the edittext.

For instance,

Quantity ***_*__**.00

I want to do something like this.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
etQuantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            stringBuilder.append(".00");

            String str = s.toString();
            String finalString = str + stringBuilder.toString();

            etQuantity.setText(finalString);
            Log.d("String", "" + finalString);

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            stringBuilder.append(".00");

            String str = s.toString();
            String finalString = str + stringBuilder.toString();

            etQuantity.setText(finalString);
            Log.d("String", "" + finalString);

        } 

    });
```

But I got an error:

```
01-30 09:49:33.541: E/AndroidRuntime(4294): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 09:49:33.541: E/AndroidRuntime(4294): java.lang.StackOverflowError
01-30 09:49:33.541: E/AndroidRuntime(4294):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1013)
01-30 09:49:33.541: E/AndroidRuntime(4294):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.getChars(SpannableStringBuilder.java:913)
01-30 09:49:33.541: E/AndroidRuntime(4294):     at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:74)
01-30 09:49:33.541: E/AndroidRuntime(4294):     at android.text.method.ReplacementTransformationMethod$ReplacementCharSequence.getChars(ReplacementTransformationMethod.java:151)
01-30 09:49:33.541: E/AndroidRuntime(4294):     at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:74)
01-30 09:49:33.541: E/AndroidRuntime(4294):     at android.text.MeasuredText.setPara(MeasuredText.java:106)
01-30 09:49:33.541: E/AndroidRuntime(4294):     at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:239)
01-30 09:49:33.541: E/AndroidRuntime(4294):     at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:284)
01-30 09:49:33.541: E/AndroidRuntime(4294):     at android.text.DynamicLayout.<init>(DynamicLayout.java:170)
01-30 09:49:33.541: E/AndroidRuntime(4294):     at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:5986)
01-30 09:49:33.541: E/AndroidRuntime(4294):     at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:5884)
01-30 09:49:33.541: E/AndroidRuntime(4294):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6423)
01-30 09:49:33.541: E/AndroidRuntime(4294):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3696)
01-30 09:49:33.541: E/AndroidRuntime(4294):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3554)
01-30 09:49:33.541: E/AndroidRuntime(4294):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
01-30 09:49:33.541: E/AndroidRuntime(4294):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3529)
01-30 09:49:33.541: E/AndroidRuntime(4294):     at com.innovalynx.vms.fragments.SalesOrderDetailFragment$1.afterTextChanged(SalesOrderDetailFragment.java:92)
01-30 09:49:33.541: E/AndroidRuntime(4294):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7247)
01-30 09:49:33.541: E/AndroidRuntime(4294):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3703)
01-30 09:49:33.541: E/AndroidRuntime(4294):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3554)
01-30 09:49:33.541: E/AndroidRuntime(4294):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
01-30 09:49:33.541: E/AndroidRuntime(4294):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3529)
01-30 09:49:33.541: E/AndroidRuntime(4294):     at com.innovalynx.vms.fragments.SalesOrderDetailFragment$1.afterTextChanged(SalesOrderDetailFragment.java:92)
01-30 09:49:33.541: E/AndroidRuntime(4294):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7247)
```

Any thing I'm doing wrong please point me to it. Your help will be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[onTextChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#onTextChanged%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) is not a place to modify text of EditText.***

From doc

*This method is called to notify you that, within s, the count characters beginning at start have just replaced old text that had length before. **It is an error to attempt to make changes to s from this callback.***

So [afterTextChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged%28android.text.Editable%29) can do the work.

---

*Using current approach, you need to some steps as remove the TextWatcher, set the text, and add the TextWatcherback to the EditText. That way, nothing is listening to your EditText changes, and will not cause the `StackOverflowError` error.*

```
etQuantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String str = s.toString();
        if (str.contains(".00")) {
            if (! str.endsWith(".00")) {
                str = str.replace(".00", "") + ".00"; 
            }
        } else {
            str = str + ".00"; 
        }
        etQuantity.removeTextChangedListener(this); // Remove listener
        etQuantity.setText(str);                    // Set Text
            etQuantity.setSelection(str.length() - 3);  // Set selection
        etQuantity.addTextChangedListener(this);    // Add back the listener 
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    } 
});
```

---

Another way is to add one more view like `TextView` for `.00`.

Comment: Yes I removed my code inside ontextchanged but it's still the same.

Comment: Add `etQuantity.setSelection(str.length() - 3); ` after setting the text. See update now....

Comment: @PankajKumar working fine +1, but if put some data and delete the data moved to next exittext view .00 is not deleting ( I wan to show the hint of the edit text when there is no data!

Comment: @PankajKumar got it we need put another check  if (str.contains("A")&&str.length()==1) for replacing .00  and  if(str.length()!=0) i1.setSelection(str.length() - 1)

Comment: @LOG_TAG Nice too know that you solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an uneditable string at end of the edittext then follow simple ways why these kind of complex codes.

Simple concatenate the extra uneditable text with your changeable text.

Is there any problem in the following code:

```
String str = "your data";
etQuantity.setText(str + ".00");

//for restrict user to delete
etQuantity.setFocusable(false); 
etQuantity.setClickable(false);
```

OR

```
String str = "your data";
etQuantity.setText(str + ".00");
etQuantity.setKeyListener(null);
```

When we can do all things with simple string operations then why to use complex method which  will sometimes make confusion.

Comment: first remove all textwatcher things and try it simply, coz i don't see anything here that will force you to use textwatcher.simply write in your general methods like onCreate or any userdefined..

Comment: can you tell me why you are using textwatcher here. only for adding thid extra text or for some other issue.

Comment: Because I let the user type for decimal

Comment: then no need to use textwatcher or no need to handle TextChangedListener here . simply add your value to the edittext with concatination of the ".00" string.

Comment: but the user can delete the .00 string. I don't want them to delete it

Comment: check my edit answer.. i.e made the edittext to noneditable after settext.